# PHP switch is not registering from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The Objective of this code is to go ahead and assign the usergroup in a different database, i have created a switch to specify what group_id belong to which role_id and Admin however it does not seem to recognise the case only the default... My Code is as follows:

```
$result2 = $DB->query("SELECT group_id, picture, joindate from ".DB_PREFIX."members where member_id = '".$member_id."'");
    if ($DB->num_rows($result)){
        $member_obj = $DB->fetch_object($result2);
    }
if (!empty($member_obj)){
    $member_group_id = $member_obj->group_id;
}

switch ($member_group_id) {
        case 1: //Admins
            $user_data['role_id'] = "16";
            $user_data['admin'] = "1";  
        break;

        case 2: //freemembers
            $user_data['role_id'] = "8";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 3: //guests
            $user_data['role_id'] = "2";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 4: //pending members
            $user_data['role_id'] = "2";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 5: //chatter package members
            $user_data['role_id'] = "34";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 6: //cancelled members
            $user_data['role_id'] = "2";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 7: //Socialite Member
            $user_data['role_id'] = "35";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 8: //socialgod members
            $user_data['role_id'] = "36";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 10: //chatadmins
            $user_data['role_id'] = "33";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;

        case 11: //forummods
            $user_data['role_id'] = "2";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;  

        default: //Guests
            $user_data['role_id'] = "8";
            $user_data['admin'] = "0";
        break;
    }
```

The SQL that is run to update the site is as follows:

```
    // new member
    if ( ! $arrUserID['user_id'] ) {

    $where_sql .= ", DateFirstVisit = '{$user_data['joindate']}',
                     DateInserted = '{$user_data['joindate']}',
                     DateUpdated = '{$user_data['joindate']}'";

    $MDB->query("INSERT INTO ".$PREFS->conf['module_vanilla_table_prefix']."User {$where_sql}");

    $arrUserID['user_id'] = $MDB->get_insert_id();

    if ( $arrUserID['user_id'] ) {
        $MDB->query("INSERT INTO ".$PREFS->conf['module_vanilla_table_prefix']."UserRole SET UserID={$arrUserID['user_id']}, RoleID={$user_data['role_id']}");
    }
}
// existing member
else {
    $MDB->query("UPDATE ".$PREFS->conf['module_vanilla_table_prefix']."User {$where_sql} WHERE UserID = {$arrUserID['user_id']} LIMIT 1");
    $MDB->query("UPDATE ".$PREFS->conf['module_vanilla_table_prefix']."UserRole SET RoleID={$user_data['role_id']} WHERE UserID = {$arrUserID['user_id']} LIMIT 1");
}
```

Just to clarify for example if $member_group_id is 1 then it should set role_id to 16 and admin to 1 however it auto defaults to role_id 8 and admin 0

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you defining that most of them are *not* admin? Why not make that the default, and just change *if* someone is an admin?

Comment: Hi @Nytrix its weird how vanilla forum works.... even if Admin = 1 the user is still not admin until the role is also set to 16...

Comment: If it's constantly default, that mean your not satisfying your second if statement before the switch which is causing $member_group_id to be blank. Do an echo to see if $member_obj has an value. This is why your defaulting on your switch.

Comment: @KenzaRooker That does not make my point invalid. You are defining `$user_data['admin'] = "0";` everytime, make that the standard (somewhere above that), but change it *only* when user should get admin priviliges. It had nothing to do with your problem, more a simple improvement for your code.

Comment: Thank you @Nytrix i will sort that out today

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for the Reply i found the answer and it is now working here is the SQL before and Answer for future reference if anyone else has this issue.

Before:

```
$result2 = $DB->query("SELECT group_id, picture, joindate from ".DB_PREFIX."members where member_id = '".$member_id."'");
    if ($DB->num_rows($result)){
        $member_obj = $DB->fetch_object($result2);
    }
if (!empty($member_obj)){
    $member_group_id = $member_obj->group_id;
}
```

On line 2 it is set to $result and not result2 which means it could not parse the info... the corrected version is as follows:

```
$result2 = $DB->query("SELECT group_id, picture, joindate from ".DB_PREFIX."members where member_id = '" . $params['member_id'] . "'");
    if ($DB->num_rows($result2)){
        $member_obj = $DB->fetch_object($result2);
    }
if (!empty($member_obj)){
    $member_group_id = $member_obj->group_id;
}
```

Thank you to those who commented!